# Attaching a Parameter to specific external links

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying to track my offline conversions for a hair salon. When a customer comes to our site the link looks like `salon.com/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwuNbsBRC-ARIsAAzITueS`. My problem occurs when I am trying to attach that GCLID to form data because the form is not filled out on our site, We used an online booking service. The service has said they would be happy to integrate handling for a parameter if we could set up the way to send it on our side.

Essentially what I want to do is grab the parameter `gclid=Cj0KCQjwuNbsBRC-ARIsAAzITueS` and when the user click any of the "book now" links it will append that parameter to the back of the external link if the gclid exists.

I have used the code below to grab the gclid but now I just need to attach it to all the external links

```
var rawURL = window.location.href; 
var url = new URL(rawURL);
var param = url.searchParams.get('gclid');
```

Essentially what I want to do is grab the parameter `gclid=Cj0KCQjwuNbsBRC-ARIsAAzITueS` and when the user click any of the "book now" links it will append that parameter to the back of the external link if the gclid exists. Therefore when they get to the new site it looks like this `bookingsite.com/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwuNbsBRC-ARIsAAzITueS` and the booking site can grab that and place it in a cookie for when the customer submits their booking.

Comment: Please, please... don't use query string for that. It's violating the code of good practices. Also you can break external links, what about pages which don't accept *any* query strings and would return an error in that situation instead?

Comment: What would you recommend? It will only be used to go to one site that accepts query strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is in wordpress, and the links all share a class, you can do it something like this:

```
var rawURL = window.location.href; 
var url = new URL(rawURL);
var param = url.searchParams.get('gclid');

jquery('.classNameHere').each(function(ind) {
    var currentHref = jQuery(this).attr('herf');
    jQuery(this).attr('href', currentHref + param);
});
```

This link showcases a better way of getting the get parameters, as URL.searchParams.get will not function with IE: https://html-online.com/articles/get-url-parameters-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work.

```js
const externalLink = document.getElementById("external")
externalLint.href += param
```